# "Hadoop archive -archiveName directoryname.har -p /source/hdfs/path /destination/hdfs/path" doesn't work via spark-submit but working in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, archive, har

I am trying to develop code in spark scala in intellij, created mvn package and doing spark-submit in cluster but it shows warn in yarn log saying "warn ioc.client: exception encountered while connecting to the server." Looks like it's not able to connect to server.
However there were no issues while I ran har command in spark shell not sure what is the issue here?

I want to know if there is any dependency which I can add to resolve this issue as I was able to execute in spark-shell but not through spark-submit
Or is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: If you're just executing hadoop cli from Scala code, that doesn't require Spark at all, so you shouldn't use either